# PHP in blogger classic template

Tags: javascript, php, html, blogger

I just need to know how to run PHP in blogger classic theme. I use blogger and google domains to run HTML code. Blogger doesn't have advanced features. It is running as a comment.

I want to run `<?php echo $_GET["body"]; ?>`

How do I fix that?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

I could use javascript to "get" from the url, but how would I do that?

Comment: could I use javascript `var url = window.locatio.href `?

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know where to start. You have called HTML: "code", but it isn't that. PHP is "code", but I'm pretty certain Blogger won't allow you to just run PHP inside a template. That would have a lot of security implications for the platform itself and for any visitors to Blogger pages.

Comment: So, the next question is: why are you trying to dump the contents of a PHP `GET` parameter in a Blogger page? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Finally, I doubt you'll have much more success running Javascript than you would with PHP. Once again, what is it you're trying to achieve

Comment: thankyou. I am going to use javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't run PHP in Blogger. What you want to do and why?

Blogger is simple CMS for posting articles, it's not platform for creating apps.

Comment: thank you. I use blogger classic template (custom HTML) so I needed to use javascript.